# SQL WHERE clause error

Tags: sql

I want to put where clause below for totalscore > 50
But when I put `where totalscore > 50` after order by there is some error.

```
SELECT 
    h.hacker_id, h.name, SUM(ss.maxscore) totalscore
FROM
    (SELECT 
         hacker_id, challenge_id, MAX(score) maxscore
     FROM 
         submission_table s
     GROUP BY 
         challenge_id, hacker_id) AS ss
JOIN 
    hacker_table h ON ss.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
GROUP BY 
    h.hacker_id
ORDER BY 
    totalscore DESC, hacker_id ASC
WHERE 
    totalscore > 50
```

Comment: WHERE goes before ORDER BY, not after. Find a SQL tutorial or book.

Comment: the correct order would be WHERE -> GROUP BY -> ORDER BY

Answer (score 2):

The others are correct regarding `WHERE` but I think from your description you want

`HAVING SUM(ss.maxscore)>50`

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for a true/false on the score being above 50 as part of the sort then you'd use:

```
ORDER BY score, totalscore>50
```

Although just adding totalscore to the order make more sense.

If your trying to only get those with a totalscore > 50 then without knowing your tables the easiest thing to do is add another subselect

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT h.hacker_id,h.name,SUM(ss.maxscore) totalscore 
      from (
        SELECT hacker_id,challenge_id,MAX(score) maxscore 
        FROM submission_table s 
        GROUP BY challenge_id,hacker_id
      ) as ss 
      JOIN hacker_table h 
      ON ss.hacker_id = h.hacker_id 
      GROUP BY h.hacker_id 
    )
    Where totalscore > 50
    Order by totalscore Desc,hacker_id ASC
```

Comment: DOH, I'd downvote my own post if I could, HAVING is a much better option, the extra SELECT will work but I use HAVING on a regular basis so should know better...